# How many candies, of which there are $5$ types, must be distributed to a classroom to guarantee at least $40$ are distributed of the same type?

Tags: combinatorics, pigeonhole-principle

Hi I have been searching how to do this question online but it feels like all the questions which are similar have an additional piece of information.

> How many candies, of which there are $5$ types, must be distributed to a classroom to guarantee at least $40$ are distributed of the same type?

Any ideas or hints? Thank you!

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this may be an example of what's called the pigeonhole principle. I like to think of it like balls and containers. Sometimes the abstraction for what should be considered the balls and what considered the containers isn't straight forward; if you think about the candy flavors here as the containers (or pigeonholes), how many people can you give a different candy to until you *must* repeat a flavor? You can only hand out five candies before you have to give someone a flavor that you've already given to someone else. You can extend this situation to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is an application of the pigeonhole principle.  If you want to avoid distributing $40$ any one type you can distribute $39$ of each.  How many is that?  Then add $1$.